# Add last Youtube video to a chanel with Youtube API - Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

How can i add (fetch) last Youtube video of a chanel with Youtube API ?

I just arrive to add (fetch) one vidéo by the video ID.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what you need to do
I have used those two steps in the past to fetch youtube data.

The documentation for this process can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-retrieve-uploads

Step 1: 
You need to find your playlist ID and retrieve it form the channel you are trying to fetch the videos

Step 2: This will give you a retrieval of a list of videos, then you need to filter for the latest uploaded video with the query string

```
?part=snippet,contentDetails,player&id={0}&key={1} - where id is the videoId returned from step 2.
```